# Automatically resize node

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

how to define size of node when used on different size devices, for example now I use

```
Node.xScale = 0.5;
Node.yScale = 0.8;
```

For Ipad size are good, but for Iphone its too big.

Answer (score 1):

Set your node size proportional to your `world` (`SKScene` or `SKNode` with same size as your `scene`).

```
Node.size = CGSizeMake(world.frame.size.width / 4, world.frame.size.height / 4)
```

In your situation you should use `self` instead of `world`

> Also variables should start with a lowercase letter.

Comment: thanks for replay, but when i use your example my node stretch when fall down. in my situation i use self not world if it makes any difference

Answer (score 1):

it kinda depends on your game..

you can do something like

```
if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone {
    scaleSize = 0.5
}

Node.xScale = scaleSize
Node.yScale = scaleSize
```

you can get more specific and size them differently depending on the width of your phone too.. it depends on what youre going for. you could always use different sets of images for different screen sizes too..